# IK Flexible Bones Twisting Mesh

Tags: bones, inverse-kinematics

I created a tentacle, added an armature, changed the bones to b bones, added ik, target null object and noticed that the bones looked twisted (without me doing anything). Once I started posing my tentacle the mesh started to get twisted at certain positions.

Model is available [here](https://hitrecord.org/records/4085145)

any tips to avoid this let me know. I appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

[image: twisted tentacle][image: wireframe view of armature]

Answer (score 0):

I was watching a tutorial today and they mentioned the roll setting for the bone. It made me think of the problem I was having with the tentacle and I went to the model, changed the roll setting to be the same on all bones and the problem has been fixed.